# Proper way to resolve the app component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, router, resolver

I am working on an application that pulls its site copy based on the domain. I have the app working with one exception. I am defining the navbar and footer of the application in the app.component template like below.

```
    <navigation></navigation>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    <appFooter></appFooter>
```

And inside of the template for appFooter and navigation I am resolving the data using the safe navifation operator like below

```
<p>{{copyService.copy?.somevalue}}</p>
```

What I would really like to do is use a resolver and ActivatedRoute's data property to do something like this

```
var copy = this.route.snapshot.data['copy'];
```

in the app component. Then pass the data through an input variable to footer and navigation.

Unfortunately I am not sure how I would go about resolving for the app component when I am redirecting to my home component like below

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

If anyone has any ideas about the best way to go about completing this task I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Please know that the code I provided is just example code and not from my actual code base I was just trying to illustrate the current issue I am having.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I was able to handle this was to add another component layer on top of the app.component.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '', 
  component: BaseComponent, 
  resolve: { 
    yourContent: contentResolver 
  }, 
  children: [ 
  { path: 'home'... }
  ]
}
```

Then move these:

```
<navigation></navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<appFooter></appFooter>
```

Into your `base.html` from your `app.html`

The resolves that you define in this BaseComponent will become available to all components within (and to all child routes).

Hope that gets you a little bit closer to what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you this did help me out.

Comment: how would you do this with multiple modules?

Comment: Is there a better way to do this in 2023.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I used https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER for loading initial content, storing the initial data in a variable in a service.